# How to copy local file to QClipboard (in Gnome)?

Tags: qt, clipboard, gnome

QClipboard offers several ways to copy stuff into the clipboard. There are high level functions for standard desktop (text, pixmaps, etc), but I could not figure out how to implement the standard copy file operation. Google did not help.

Answer (score 3):

Just put appropriate mime type and URL of the local file into clipboard. [Docs reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html#details).

```
QMimeData* mimeData = new QMimeData();
mimeData->setData("text/uri-list", "file:///C:/fileToCopy.txt");
clipboard->setMimeData(mimeData);
```

You can use static method [QUrl::fromLocalFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fromLocalFile) to get QUrl instance to be used in `mimeData->setData` :

```
mimeData->setData("text/uri-list", QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/fileToCopy.txt"));
```

Comment: There is shortcut for the above: `mimeData->setUrls({QUrl::fromLocalFile(C:/fileToCopy.txt)});`

Answer (score 2):

Okay I found the solution to my problem. The problem is that gnome (working on linux) does its own thing. The file(s) are not stored in the `text/uri-list` format like N1ghtLight mentioned, but uses the special  `x-special/gnome-copied-files` format. The following code did it:

```
//  Get clipboard
QClipboard *cb = QApplication::clipboard();

// Ownership of the new data is transferred to the clipboard.
QMimeData* newMimeData = new QMimeData();

// Copy old mimedata
const QMimeData* oldMimeData = cb->mimeData();
for ( const QString &f : oldMimeData->formats())
    newMimeData->setData(f, oldMimeData->data(f));

// Copy path of file
newMimeData->setText(_file->absolutePath());

// Copy file
newMimeData->setUrls({QUrl::fromLocalFile(_file->absolutePath())});

// Copy file (gnome)
QByteArray gnomeFormat = QByteArray("copy\n").append(QUrl::fromLocalFile(_file->absolutePath()).toEncoded());
newMimeData->setData("x-special/gnome-copied-files", gnomeFormat);

// Set the mimedata
cb->setMimeData(newMimeData);
```

Comment: Also, In the Gnome case, multiple files must be separated by a new line `'\n'`. Trailing new line is not allowed, however.