Cut a file to be pasted in a file manager
I want to put a file in the OS clipboard. I am using Qt6. The windows code works, the Unix code is failing. The file is copied, and the original file is left.
    auto clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
    auto mimeData = new QMimeData();
    auto urls = QList<QUrl>();

    urls.append(QUrl::fromLocalFile(selectedFilePath));
    mimeData->setUrls(urls);
#if defined(Q_OS_MAC) || defined(Q_OS_UNIX) || defined(Q_OS_LINUX)
    mimeData->setData("application/x-cut-operation", QByteArray("true"));
#elif defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    // 2 for cut and 5 for copy
    int dropEffect = 2;
    QByteArray dataForClipboard;
    QDataStream stream(&dataForClipboard, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
    stream << dropEffect;
    mimeData->setData("Preferred DropEffect", dataForClipboard);
    // Should catch: Q_OS_FREEBSD, Q_OS_NETBSD, Q_OS_OPENBSD, and Q_OS_LINUX
#else
    qWarning() << "Cut operation is not supported on this platform.";
#endif
    clipboard->setMimeData(mimeData);

See also cut and paste clipboard exchange between Qt application and Windows Explorer
EDIT:
The following code enables copy on plasma6. Still no cut.
   // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612779/how-to-copy-local-file-to-qclipboard-in-gnome
    QByteArray gnomeFormat =
        QByteArray("cut\n").append(QUrl::fromLocalFile(selectedFilePath).toEncoded());
    mimeData->setData("x-special/gnome-copied-files", gnomeFormat);


Is selectedFilePath an absolute path?

To my knowledge, Linux does not have the concept of copying files between applications (this is not needed, as the shell only needs copying and pasting of texts, having a graphic file manager is for Windows dummies only).
If you are using X11 as a GUI to Linux, then the documentation of Qt says this:

Since there is no standard way to copy and paste files between
applications on X11, various MIME types and conventions are currently
in use. For instance, Nautilus expects files to be supplied with a
x-special/gnome-copied-files MIME type with data beginning with the
cut/copy action, a newline character, and the URL of the file.

EDIT:
These mime types only work on GMOME file managers obviously. For different desktops, you might try:

KDE: replace 'x-special/gnome-copied-files' with 'x-special/KDE-copied-files'
MATE: replace 'x-special/gnome-copied-files' with 'x-special/mate-copied-files'
XFCE: replace 'x-special/gnome-copied-files' with 'x-special/mate-copied-files'


Sorry to inform you, but this actually works. If you do not add the mime data - I can copy on Plasma5 and Plasma6. Cut is the part thats not working for me.

What I wanted to state is that if I read the documentation correctly that there is no uniform way to achieve copy and paste under Linux. The pasting relies on the Mime-Information and even though Mac OS under the hood is a lot of Unix, the mime-spec seems to differ.
